# Can I say 'three next of kin'?

Tags: uncountable-nouns

This headline ([**today**](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-42843841)) tells me that the three victims of a tragic road incident were from different families, but maybe not three different families.

> The boys' next of kin **have** been informed, the Met Police said.

Could it have been worded 'the boys' **three** next of kin' ?

---

Edit : I have now found a very obscure reference :

> ... the two next of kin by the father and the two by the mother ...

[An Institute of the Law of Scotland](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=gFiZ1IvwOHAC&pg=PA205&dq=two+next+of+kin&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie37G3tvjYAhWDJ8AKHWsGBe0Q6AEIXTAJ#v=onepage&q=two%20next%20of%20kin&f=false)

Comment: [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/next_of_kin) says “treated as singular or plural”, so I’d say yes to the original title question before the edit (viz., that _next of kin_ can be plural). Whether or not it’s **countable** is another matter. Doesn’t sound right to me.

Comment: Just like lines of succession, isn't there a whole string of next(s) of kin?

Comment: @Lawrence So 'nexts' of kin is legitimate ?

Comment: @NigelJ Upon reflection, probably not in that context. Consider: "*Who **are** your next of kin?*" I was trying to say that one can have a plurality of people who (in succession) would be considered the same person's *next of kin*.

Comment: @NigelJ Consider the hypothetical case of Alice and Bob being parents of Charlie, their only child. *Both* Alice and Bob (i.e. more than one person) might be listed as Charlie's *next of kin*.

Comment: @Lawrence If it is unspecific, does that make it uncountable ? I am thinking that the only way the Police could have worded it would be 'the three families of the three boys have been informed' - in order to make clear that three families were involved, not one of three siblings or two with one/two siblings.

Comment: To make it clear that there were multiple families involved, they could have written “The next of kin of each of the three boys have been informed”. At least to me, that rules out the possibility that it’s only one family. To make it clear that it’s _three_ families, they would indeed have to say so outright; I cannot think of any way to phrase that completely unambiguously without going into mathematical-legalese nonsense (“the single individual and non-intersecting family of each of the three boys”, I suppose).

Comment: But the article **doesn’t** actually say anything about whether the three boys came from one, two, or three families. Even if there had only been one boy, they would still likely have written, “The boy’s next of kin have been informed”.

Comment: Being unspecific doesn’t make it uncountable. “The chairs” doesn’t say how many, but *chairs* remains countable there. The issue here might be related to the way *next* is used normally: you might say “the next 3 boys” but “the 3 nexts” or even “the 3 next boys” doesn’t sound *quite* as good. I think it’s more natural to put the number *after* ‘next’, not before it: “the next 3 of kin”, or even “the next several of kin”.

Comment: "The boys' three next of kin have been informed" sounds perfectly fine to my Midwest US ears.

Comment: It is *British* English news though... *next* doesn't get inflected here. Or counted, generally.

Comment: @WillCrawford I still think that the whole phrase 'next of kin' is singular, myself. It means the nearest living relative, of which there is only one.

Comment: I see what you mean, but the *have* (as emphasised in the question) agrees with the *boys'*. And there may be one for each boy without changing the meaning of the phrase?

Comment: (I still think *next-of-kin* should be hyphenated, anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very, very unlikely but not quite impossible. The governor here is context.

Even that plural possessive "the boys'…" won't make "… three next of kin" clear to most listeners. Ears just don't work that way.

One might get away with "all three next of kin… ", which should prolly be "nexts…"

One would be successful with "all three boys' next(s) of kin… ".